# I am trying to send stdout message to mailx -- Red Hat

Tags: echo

All, thanks for your help... This should be easy:

My script prints this to stdout/terminal perfectly... its pretty in the script but not below... ???? :

```
# Print to stdout
echo "------- CAPACITY TEST FAILED -------"
echo -n "  SYSTEM NAME: " ; uname -n
echo -n "  USER DETAIL: " ; whoami
echo "  PARTITION:   $PART "
echo "  USED SPACE:  $USEDSPC "
echo "  THRESHOLD LIMIT OF $THRESH% EXCEEDED"
echo "------------------------------------"
```

I have tried numerous mailx options/formats but coming up a few fry's short of a 'happy meal'... Any help is awesome.

Please note I cannot change the red hat server in any way, shape, or form... frankly they don't want me breathing on it... my job is to script around it!1

Comment: First post sorry:  I want to output this multiline stdout message into a mailx body and have it formatted nicely

Comment: #stdout format ------- CAPACITY TEST FAILED -------
  SYSTEM NAME: cdpra05a0400
  USER DETAIL: u626844
  PARTITION:   /dev/sda1
  USED SPACE:  22
  THRESHOLD LIMIT OF 20% EXCEEDED
------------------------------------
only prettier

Answer (score 4):

If you pipe some stdout into mailx's stdin, it will send that as the contents of the email

```
echo "test body" | mailx -s test_subject username@example.com
```

If your script just runs and only outputs that output, you should be able to get your desired result with the following:

```
/path/to/script | mailx -s subject_here username@example.com
```

If this bit of bash is just part of a bigger script, you can get all of this to be sent over email by combining all of your above lines into one big fat echo:

```
echo -e "------- CAPACITY TEST FAILED -------\n  SYSTEM NAME: $(uname -n)\n  USER DETAIL: $(whoami)\n  PARTITION:   $PART \n  USED SPACE:  $USEDSPC \n  THRESHOLD LIMIT OF $THRESH% EXCEEDED\n------------------------------------" | mailx -s subject_here username@example.com
```

Comment: +1. you can also use a heredoc instead of all those `echo` statements. e.g. `cat <<EOF | mailx -s test_subject username@example.com` followed by the text (and shell variables), followed by `EOF` on a line by itself.  Also, quoted strings can be multi-line so you don't need `echo -e` and `\n` inside the double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your script, you can also  create a sub-shell by adding "(" ")" and pipe its output:

```
(echo "------- CAPACITY TEST FAILED -------"
 echo -n "  SYSTEM NAME: " ; uname -n
 echo -n "  USER DETAIL: " ; whoami
 echo "  PARTITION:   $PART "
 echo "  USED SPACE:  $USEDSPC "
 echo "  THRESHOLD LIMIT OF $THRESH% EXCEEDED"
 echo "------------------------------------" ) | mailx ...
```